# Why TCL threads are not printing the output

Tags: multithreading, tcl

I am using TCL threads. I am trying to write a simple program that will open 3 threads and just a simple print statement in each thread.

Below is my code

```
package require Thread
puts "*** I'm thread [thread::id]"
# Create 3 threads
for {set thread 1} {$thread <= 3} {incr thread} {
    set id [thread::create {
    # Print a hello message 3 times, waiting
    # a random amount of time between messages
        for {set i 1} {$i <= 3} {incr i} {
            after [expr { int(500*rand()) }]
            puts "Thread [thread::id] says hello"
        }
    }] ;# thread::create
    puts "*** Started thread $id"
} ;# for
puts "*** Existing threads: [thread::names]"
# Wait until all other threads are finished
while {[llength [thread::names]] > 1} {
after 500
}
puts "*** That's all, folks!"
```

Below is the output

```
*** I'm thread tid00004028
*** Started thread tid0000A5E8
*** Started thread tid00009F28
*** Started thread tid00009D54
*** Existing threads: tid00009D54 tid00009F28 tid0000A5E8 tid00004028
*** That's all, folks!
```

Comment: Works for me when I try that exact code.

Comment: What is it printing? Can you show the output

Comment: I am using Tcl 8.4 in windows

Comment: @DonalFellows: my requirement is to spawn multiple process and get there output. Apart from threading is there any other solution?

Comment: Same code works for me toooo.. Try to execute same code in tclsh8.6. i am using 8.6 version. it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since from the comments you are using Tcl 8.4, the advice you are going to get is simple: ***upgrade*** to a supported version of Tcl. I've tried the exact code you posted with both tclsh8.5 and tclsh8.6 on OSX, and both produced exactly the output one might expect. Here's a run with 8.5:

```
*** I'm thread tid0x7fff758f3180
*** Started thread tid0x104326000
*** Started thread tid0x1043ac000
*** Started thread tid0x1044b2000
*** Existing threads: tid0x1044b2000 tid0x1043ac000 tid0x104326000 tid0x7fff758f3180
Thread tid0x1043ac000 says hello
Thread tid0x104326000 says hello
Thread tid0x104326000 says hello
Thread tid0x1044b2000 says hello
Thread tid0x1043ac000 says hello
Thread tid0x1044b2000 says hello
Thread tid0x104326000 says hello
Thread tid0x1044b2000 says hello
Thread tid0x1043ac000 says hello
*** That's all, folks!
```

The thread-IDs may be quite different on other platforms (their format is not part of the spec) but that should be the sort of thing you get. Modulo variation in ordering, of course.

Tcl 8.4 is no longer supported for even security fixes; it was end-of-life'd after 8.4.20 was released.

Comment: Just for information purpose, my question is, Is Thread package inbuilt in tclsh8.6? where Thread package is not there when i am trying to access Thread using tclsh8.4. Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: The thread package was external in 8.4. It should be present with 8.6 unless someone does a really bare-bones build that skips all the contributed packages.